# How to write condition one only time?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to write a condition `!AUTH_DISABLED` only one time how to implement it?

```
if (
    (graphqlErrors && graphqlErrors.message.contains("401") && !AUTH_DISABLED) ||
    (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401 && !AUTH_DISABLED)
){
    session.login()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!AUTH_DISABLED && (graphqlErrors && graphqlErrors.message.contains("401")) ||
    (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401)){
    session.login()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your condition out in another if or just concatenate with `&&` operator:

```
if (!AUTH_DISABLED && (
      (graphqlErrors && graphqlErrors.message.contains("401")) ||
      (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401)
   )
){
    session.login()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe throw errors or do something on else, later you may encounter problems if you do not handle them. xD

```js
if (!AUTH_DISABLED && graphqlErrors && networkError ) {

  const graphqlErrors_401 = graphqlErrors.message.contains("401")
  const networkError_401 = networkError.statusCode

  if (graphqlErrors_401 || networkError_401 === 401) {
    session.login()
  } else { // throw error or do something else 
  }
} else { // do something else when auth is disabled
}
```

Comment: `graphqlErrors && graphqlErrors_401` - you're checking if `graphqlErrors` is valid *after* using it `graphqlErrors.message.contains("401")`. This will cause an error if `graphqlErrors` is `null` or `undefined` or `false` (or whatever it might otherwise be).

Comment: True, i'll change it